# How large is the struct underlying a map in golang?

Tags: go, hashmap

I know that map is a reference type in Go (it has a pointer to the map entries memory region in its underlying struct). However, I would like to know what is the size of the underlying struct of the map because I want to know if using a pointer to a map as a function argument would be faster than not using a pointer.

Looking at this [blog post](https://dave.cheney.net/2018/05/29/how-the-go-runtime-implements-maps-efficiently-without-generics) it seems that the maptype struct has a lot of fields and that it would take a long time to copy (relative to a pointer).

Looking through the golang standard libraries I have found almost no use of *map[x]x so I guess using just map[x]x should be efficient as a function argument. So this leads me to think that maybe the compiler actually replaces map[x]x by a pointer to the maptype struct. Is that the case? If not what actually is happening that may avoid the copying of the maptype struct with its many fields?

Answer (score 1):

The zero value for a Go `map` variable is a `nil` pointer.

```
var m map[string]int
```

`make` intializes a `map` and sets the `map` variable to point to a package `runtime` `hmap` `struct`.

```
m = make(map[string]int)
```

In Go, all arguments are passed by value. In the case of a `map` value, a reference type, a `map` value is a pointer. Therefore, passing a `map` value as a function or method argument is fast, you are passing a pointer.

The Go `map` `runtime` `struct`s are currently located in the `src/runtime/map.go` Go source file. Since you only see a `hmap` pointer, their size is unlikely to be relevant.

See [GopherCon 2016: Keith Randall - Inside the Map Implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl7mi9QmLns).

Comment: Thanks @peterso. Any link to a resource where it says that a map becomes a hmap pointer and not just hmap? I looked at the go/map.go but couldn't find any mention to that.